# Can I use the same domain to send outgoing only emails from another server?

Tags: email, postfix, email-server

The company currently uses gMail apps for incoming/outgoing emails. It has sending limits which I need to get around. Can I set up (say) postfix for outgoing only email on the local server? Can it bypass going through gMail's mail servers? Will it be on the same domain or should I set it up on a subdomain (e.g. noreply@noreply.example.com?

Are there specific DNS entries that I need to pay attention to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use other servers to send e-mail for your domain. You just need to make proper adjustments to your DNS `SPF` record, which indicate that the other server is allowed to send e-mail for the domain.

http://www.spfwizard.net is a tool which helps you to generate the SPF record.